# RMPath jumps on [mapView moveToLatLong:] call

Tags: ios, route-me

I am using Route-Me library to display a map on iOS. And `RMPath` class to display route path on the map. But the route path jumps on `[mapView moveToLatLong:]` call.

It happens because the map changes it's position on the screen but the route path doesn't change it at the same moment. It changes position on the screen with little delay. But if I scroll map with gestures there is no this issue.

Is it any possibility to fix the issue?

Comment: Doesn't look like the project is being maintained, but you could file a github issue.

Comment: Could you please share a [short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem? As it stands it's not clear how to reproduce the issue.